# Error while implementing ngRx "Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Actions<Action>'."

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am using the below versions:

- @ngrx/effects@8.6.0
- @ngrx/store@8.6.0
- @ngrx/core@1.2.0
- @angular/cli@8.3.25

imports:

```
import { BookService } from './../services/book.service';
import {Actions, Effect, ofType} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {mergeMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as types from './action.types';
import * as bookActions from './book.actions';
```

constructor:

```
constructor(private service: BookService,
        private actions$: Actions){}
```

---

```
@Effect() loadBooks$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<bookActions.loadBooksAction>(types.LOAD_BOOKS),
        mergeMap(() => 
            this.service.getAllBooks().pipe(map(books => 
                new bookActions.loadBooksSuccessAction(books)))
        )
    )
```

The Error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Actions'.

Comment: Please share your imports, I think there is the error.

Comment: Ok, pls show your constructor too.

Comment: updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing ngrx v8 use new [syntax](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing) so you may want to check it with your code

Sample from the docs

```
search$ = createEffect(() => ({
  // assign default values
  debounce = 300,
  scheduler = asyncScheduler
} = {}) =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BookActions.search),
    debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
    ...
  )
);
```

Secondly remove package-lock.json and `@ngrx/core` package (no need for this) in your package.json

And update package.json like this

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
```

Then run

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i
```

You can delete node_modules folder and run `npm i` if the problem still exist

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the dependency `@ngrx/core@1.2.0`. It's an old version and deprecated package for `ngrx`.

You have to remove it.

Comment: remove it and install the latest one?

Comment: but the latest version is itself of 1.2.0 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/core

Comment: no just remove it. Recent version of `ngrx` need only `store` and `effects`.

Comment: Check your other dependencies into `package.json`. Backup `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` and try to reinstall all dependencies with `yarn install`.

Comment: I'm not using the yarn package manager is it necessary to use it? I'm just new to angular pardon me if i'm being stupid

Comment: no problem! there isn't any stupid question. If `npm`, remove `package-lock.json`, remove `node_modules` folder, and execute `npm install`.